# Can't import image in image view

Tags: android

When I run this code:

```
android:src="@drawable/cake"
```

it shows an error:

> Error:(38, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/cake').

[image]

Comment: Please check the link to screenshot

Comment: post your xml code here

Answer (score 0):

Check if your image file is inside your project folders

Comment: Yes it is. See the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to all drawable folders. Then it should work.

- /drawable-ldpi For low density screens
- /drawable-mdpi For medium density screens
- /drawable-hdpi For high resolution screens
- /drawable-xhdpi For extra high resolution screens

Answer (score 0):

have you pasted your desired image in your drawable folder?